# Covariance of a convolution between a gaussian random walk and white noise

Tags: covariance, stationarity, convolution

I want to compute the covariance of $$U_t:=\sum_{l=-L}^{l=L} (X_l-X_{l-1})X_{l-t}$$
with $X_t$ defined as : \begin{align*}
    X_0&=0
    \\
    X_t&=X_{t-1}+\epsilon_t
\end{align*}
$t=1,2,...$ 
$\epsilon_t \sim N(0,1)$
$\epsilon_t$ are i.i.d
$Var(X_t)=t$ since they are i.i.d
$Cov(X_{t},X_{t-k})=t-k$ again with the same argument since they are iid.
clearly E[$U_t$]=0.
Now for the covariance I've computed this :
\begin{align*}
   Cov(U_t,U_{t+\tau})&=Cov\Bigg\{\sum_{l=-L}^{l=L}(X_l-X_{l-1})X_{l-t},\sum_{p=-L}^{p=L}(X_p-X_{p-1})X_{p-t+\tau}\Bigg\}
   \\
   &=\sum_{l=-L}^{l=L}\sum_{p=-L}^{p=L}Cov((X_l-X_{l-1})X_{l-t},(X_p-X_{p-1})X_{p-t+\tau})
   \\
   &=\sum_{l=-L}^{l=L}\sum_{p=-L}^{p=L}\bigg(E((X_l-X_{l-1})X_{l-t}(X_p-X_{p-1})X_{l-t+\tau})-E((X_l-X_{l-1})X_{l-t})E((X_p-X_{p-1})X_{p-t+\tau)})\bigg)
   \\
   &=\sum_{l=-L}^{l=L}\sum_{p=-L}^{p=L}\bigg(E((X_l-X_{l-1})X_{l-t})E((X_p-X_{p-1})X_{l-t+\tau})+E((X_l-X_{l-1})(X_p-X_{p-1})E(X_{l-t}X_{p-t+\tau})
   \\
   &+E((X_l-X_{l-1})X_{p-t+\tau})E(X_{l-t}(X_p-X_{p-1}))-E((X_l-X_{l-1})X_{l-t})E((X_p-X_{p-1})X_{p-t+\tau})\bigg)
   \\
   &=\sum_{l=-L}^{l=L}\sum_{p=-L}^{p=L}0+\delta_{l \leq p-t+\tau \cap p \leq l-t }+0 + \sum_{l=-L}^{l=L}\sum_{p=-L}^{p=L} \tau \delta_{l=p}
   \\
&=\sum_{l=-L}^{l=L}\sum_{p=-L}^{p=L}0+\delta_{p \leq l-t }+0 + \sum_{l=-L}^{l=L}\sum_{p=-L}^{p=L} \tau \delta_{l=p}\\
   &=(2L-t)^2 + 2L\tau
   \end{align*}
Where we used on the third line Isserli's theorem and the fourth line,we used that $$X_l-X_{l-1}=\epsilon_l$$ and since they are iid,$$Cov(\epsilon_l,\epsilon_p)=0 \text{for} p \neq l$$ since $E(X_t)=E(\epsilon_t)=0 \forall x,t$ we have that $$Cov(\epsilon_l,\epsilon_p)=E(\epsilon_l,\epsilon_p)=0$$
the $\delta_{l \leq p-t+\tau \cap p \leq l-t }$ comes from the fact that $$E((X_l-X_{l-1})X_{p-t+\tau})E(X_{l-t}(X_p-X_{p-1}))=1*1$$ since $$E((X_l-X_{l-1})X_{p-t+\tau})=Cov((X_l-X_{l-1}),X_{p-t+\tau})=Cov(\epsilon_l,X_{p-t+\tau})=1$$ since $X_{p-t+\tau}=\sum_{j=0}^{p-t+\tau}\epsilon_j$ by the same argument as before since the epsilons are iid, we get 1. We repeat the same reasoning for $E(X_{l-t}(X_p-X_{p-1}))$.
the zeros comes from the fact that
$$E((X_l-X_{l-1})X_{l-t})=0$$ since $\epsilon_l$ is not contained in $X_{l-t}$
Moreover,if l=p, then
\begin{align*}
       E((X_l-X_{l-1})(X_p-X_{p-1})E(X_{l-t}X_{p-t+\tau})&=Var(\epsilon_p)*Cov(X_{p-t+\tau},X_{p})\\
       &=Var(\epsilon_p)*\tau
   \end{align*}\
Is this results true ? I'm tempted to say yes since it seems to be non stationary. But I feel that I'm missing something in the order of summation. My question is can someone show me the true expression of the covariance of such process.

Comment: Your sum is undefined because you haven't defined $X_t$ for any negative $t.$